# Swift app global variable in UserDefaults

Tags: dependency-injection, userdefaults, swift5

I am designing an app that requires translation in 2 languages. The translations are requested from a server.

I created a struct TranslationService which stores all translations and has a function that returns translated phrase based on code

```
struct TranslationService: Codable {
var translations: [Translation]

func getTranslation(by code: String) -> String? {
    let result = translations.filter { $0.string == code }

    return result.first?.translation
}
```

So on startup in the **AppDelegate** I am doing a request to the server in order to get the translations and when the request is done I create a **TranslationService** and set the **translations** array to be equal to the server response array.

Next, I am wondering which of the two options is better:

**Option 1:** Pass it to the **rootController** and spread it everywhere in the app through constructor dependency injection

**Option 2:** Save it in **UserDefaults** and retrieve it in every ViewController and use it if present

Comment: Why not Singleton?

Comment: I read articles about Singleton and in 2 of them, I noticed they recommended Dependency Injection as a better option. Singletons looked like a very good option to me but after I read the articles I decided to ask here.

Comment: It is considered as anti pattern but not for all cases - and I think your your kind of problem it would work great. At least way better then UserDefaults

Comment: Thanks, I guess for my purpose it is right to use Singleton because I'll seed data in it and will not alter it throughout the application's life. Maybe it is anti-pattern if you are storing data that is constantly changing.